# Loosing geojson's feature property information when visualising by using folium

Tags: geojson, geopandas, folium

currently I have already made a geojson file (called **output**):
`{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [ {"type": "Feature",  "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [103.815381, 1.279109]}, "properties": {"temperature": 24, "marker-symbol": "park", "marker-color": "#AF4646"}},  {"type": "Feature",  "geometry":  {"type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [[[103.809297, 1.294906], [103.799445, 1.283906], [103.815381, 1.294906]]]}, "properties": {"temperature": 24, "stroke": "#AF4646"}}]}`

It contains a multiline string type and a point type. The expected output should be like this (visualised by using geojson.io), **where all the properties (e.g. colour of string and the marker, the forest icon of the marker) are all kept**:
[image]

My goal is to generate an html or an image file (the best choice) of this map. So I turned to folium. However, when I use command:

`m = folium.Map(location=[1.2791,103.8154], zoom_start=12)`
`folium.GeoJson(output, name='test').add_to(m)`
`m.save('map.html')`
The visualisation is like this:
[image]
Where all the property information has been wiped out. Are there any way to keep those property information? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Provided GeoJSON (`output`) contains styling properties defined in [`simplestyle` spec](https://github.com/mapbox/simplestyle-spec) which are not supported by leaflet `L.geoJSON`

[`leaflet-simplestyle` plugin](https://github.com/rowanwins/leaflet-simplestyle) could be utilized which *extends* `L.geoJSON` to support the simplestyle spec, here is a an example on how to utilize it in folium

```
import folium
from folium.elements import JSCSSMixin
from folium.map import Layer
from jinja2 import Template


class StyledGeoJson(JSCSSMixin, Layer):
    """
    Creates a GeoJson which supports.

    """
    _template = Template(u"""
        {% macro script(this, kwargs) %}

            var {{ this.get_name() }} = L.geoJson({{ this.data }},
                {
                    useSimpleStyle: true,
                    useMakiMarkers: true
                }
            ).addTo({{ this._parent.get_name() }});
        {% endmacro %}
        """)  

    default_js = [
        ('leaflet-simplestyle', 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet-simplestyle'),
    ]

    def __init__(self, data,name=None, overlay=True, control=True, show=True):
        super(StyledGeoJson, self).__init__(name=name, overlay=overlay,
                                       control=control, show=show)
        self._name = 'StyledGeoJson'
        self.data = data
```

Usage

```
output = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [ {"type": "Feature",  "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [103.815381, 1.279109]}, "properties": {"temperature": 24, "marker-symbol": "park", "marker-color": "#AF4646"}},  {"type": "Feature",  "geometry":  {"type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [[[103.809297, 1.294906], [103.799445, 1.283906], [103.815381, 1.294906]]]}, "properties": {"temperature": 24, "stroke": "#AF4646"}}]}
m = folium.Map(location=[1.2791,103.8154], zoom_start=14)

StyledGeoJson(output).add_to(m)
m
```

**Result**

[image]